# Report class and appendix package: All appendices as roman-lettered sections under one chapter

Tags: chapters, appendices, report, appendix

I am using the `report` class and the `appendix` package, and I'd like to have an un-numbered chapter called `Appendices`, where every appendix is a *section* named `Appendix X` under said chapter. The numbering ought to be robust in the table of contents, too: the prefix numbering of each appendix should be `\Alph`. The way `appendix` is defined, each appendix is a chapter, which seems a *little* overkill.

I'm not sure if an MWE even applies here.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[toc,title]{appendix}

\begin{appendices}
    \section{First appdx}
    \section{Second appdx}
\end{appendices}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `appendix` package provides the machinery you need. Fortunately, it's not difficult to provide the needed setup instructions -- specifically, `\addcontentsline`, `\setcounter`, and `\renewcommand\thesection` directives -- yourself.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Conclusion}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Conclusion}

\chapter*{Appendices}
%% provide three setup instructions:
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices} % write to the toc file
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}

\section{First appendix}
\section{Second appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Much obliged: I think this is also simpler and fits the flow of the rest of the content better than the `appendix` package.